# Should security be implemented with this timer?

Tags: c#, security, func

I'm trying to create a reusable timer in my application. To do this, I believe the solution is to pass a function to the timer that should be ran at every specified interval. However, I'm concerned with how secure this might not be as is. 
Should I require some form of verification to confirm the function came from within the application and not some malicious third party? What would be some ways of doing this?

I'm considering using `System.Security.Cryptography` to create a unique key each time the application starts up and reference that. If there's a simpler way, please let me know. The code in question is below.

Edit:
The biggest concern is that by passing a function to a timer I open up the possibility of code injection. Additionally, only functions from the same namespace are going to be used.

```
private System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

protected void InitializeTimer(Func<int> CommandToExecute, bool isAutoReset = false, bool isElapsedEnabled = false, int millisecondInterval = 30000)
        {
            timer.AutoReset = isAutoReset;
            timer.Enabled = isElapsedEnabled;
            timer.Interval = millisecondInterval;
            timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => CommandToExecute();
        }
```

Comment: I am confused as to what problem you are trying to solve.  How many places can the timer event fire from?  Arent they all authorized?  Or are you afraid the person at the keyboard will change?

Comment: Unless you actually go out of your way to make it possible for code to be injected into your application, it isn't possible for a managed delegate to come from anywhere but your own process code. If a malicious third party had the ability to inject arbitrary code in your process, it would also have the ability to bypass your verification (by injecting more code to set this up). As Raymond Chen would put it, you're already on the wrong side of the airtight hatchway if this is ever a concern.

Comment: Thanks, Jeroen. That makes sense. Ňɏssa, I could've been more clear. My concern is with code injection.